# React Div Panel Built Using React Hooks throws Violation: Element Type is Invalid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

This React div panel is contructed using React hooks and is designed to be used with drag and drop capability.  However, it throws an Invariant Violation:  Element Type Invalid on rendering.

The panel is built with react hooks in Meteor like follows.

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from 'react';
import update from 'immutability-helper';
import ProjectItemPreview from './ProjectItemPreview.js';

export const ProjectItemsPanel = () => {
  {
    //const [cards, setCards] = defineInitialState(props.projectID);
    
    const [cards, setCards] = useState([
      {
        id: 1,
        text: 'Write a cool JS library',
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        text: 'Make it generic enough',
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        text: 'Write README',
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        text: 'Create some examples',
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        text:
          'Spam in Twitter and IRC to promote it (note that this element is taller than the others)',
      },
      {
        id: 6,
        text: '???',
      },
      {
        id: 7,
        text: 'PROFIT',
      },
    ]);
    const moveCard = useCallback(
      (dragIndex, hoverIndex) => {
        const dragCard = cards[dragIndex];
        setCards(
          update(cards, {
            $splice: [
              [dragIndex, 1],
              [hoverIndex, 0, dragCard],
            ],
          }),
        );
      },
      [cards],
    );
    const renderCard = (card, index) => {
      return (
        <ProjectItemPreview
          key={card.id}
          index={index}
          id={card.id}
          text={card.text}
          moveCard={moveCard}
        />
      );
    };
    return (
        <div>{cards.map((card, i) => renderCard(card, i))}</div>
    );
  }
};

export default ProjectItemsPanel;
```

Using component in EditProject.js as follows:

```
import ProjectItemsPanel from './ProjectItemsPanel.js';
...
                        <DndProvider backend={HTML5Backend}>
                            <ProjectItemsPanel />
                        </DndProvider>
```

Executing and trying to render the panel in a page results in the following error:

> Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a
> string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite
> components) but got: object.
>
> Check the render method of `ProjectItemsPanel`.

Changing to this import has no effect:

```
import {ProjectItemsPanel} from './ProjectItemsPanel.js';
```

Comment: I think we need to see `ProjectItemPreview.js`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are following named export, the right way to import the component is:

```
import {ProjectItemsPanel} from './ProjectItemsPanel.js';
```

Also, by looking at the code, it could be an issue with the child component `<ProjectItemPreview/>` as well, which you have imported within this file.

If the import method of `<ProjectItemPreview/>` is wrong, it will result in the same error as you have mentioned above.